# Channel Tabs not responding on Mirth 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, java-8, mirth

I'm in the position where I have to use only a specific version of Mirth (3.2.1.7650) as my work environment uses it.

I installed 3.2.1 in a different directory while i have 3.4.2 in another. When I logged into the 3.2.1 Mirth, I cannot access the channels tab while I can access all other tabs. I took the .exe file from the archives of Mirth official site (mirthconnect-3.2.1.7650.b40-windows-x64). Im using 1.8 version of JAVA. Same version is used on other system but its working on that system.

Please let me know the solution if someone has face this problem before

Comment: If the backend is for a different version of Mirth than the application you are using, then you could have several issues depending on your configuration. 3.4 has many differences from the 3.2 version. I would also recommend that you don't  to make any production changes using a version that doesn't match the db.

Comment: Thanks Gavin,
I'm communicating to my local machine as of now mimicking a SOAP webservice using SOAP UI. I'm using Mirth 3.2.1 in my local system, this communication does not happen, then I started trouble shooting to discover that the channels tab itself is not working. Little strange so tried reinstalling, still the result is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. I got an answer from the Mirth forum for this problem. Please use the below link to understand the reason for this problem. If any one get's this problem and it does not solve as per the below provided reason, please feel free to comment or post as a response for my answer.

http://www.mirthproject.org/community/forums/showthread.php?t=216949

I'm accepting this answer as of now